# Почему "Success" не выводится после удачной записи в БД?

Tags: php

```
 <?php
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO records(title, text, date) VALUES ('$_POST[post_title]', '$_POST[post_text]', NOW())", $db);

 if(mysql_query($sql)) {
    echo "Success";
 }
 ?>
```

Почему "Success" не выводится после удачной записи в БД?

Answer (score 1):

Пишите так, как написали iPro или M11
Но если этот код вы используете на реальном сайте, то перед выполнением запроса **обязательно** обработайте запрос с помощью функции mysql_real_escape_string() (для защиты от так называемых SQL-иньекций, как писал aldem67):

```
<?php $sql = 'здесь ваш запрос';
    mysql_real_escape_string($sql);
    if (mysql_query($sql)) echo 'Success';
?>
```

Comment: >mysql_real_escape_string($sql);
Нужно не запрос обрабатывать, а данные, которые в этот запрос вставляем

Comment: @aldem67, спасибо за замечание. Как-то не обращал на это внимание, посмотрел примеры на php.net, действительно везде обрабатываюся только данные запроса.
Но, что интересно, и мой способ тоже вполне работает ( имею 2 сайта, на которых исользую mysqli::real_escape_string() таким способом, проблем не наблюдал). Сорри за оффтоп

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вы вызываете 2 раза mysql_query()? В переменной $sql хранится состояние вашего запроса, а вы при этом пытаетесь выполнить еще один SQL запрос в условии, естественно что там false будет и надпись не выведется.

Правильный код

```
<?php
 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO records(title, text, date) VALUES ('$_POST[post_title]', '$_POST[post_text]', NOW())", $db);

 if($sql) {
    echo "Success";
 }
?>
```

Comment: я так тоже писал. Ничего не выводится

Answer (score 0):

У Вас логическая ошибка. Первый SQL вызывается и результат записывается в $sql, потом вы результат пытаетесь выполнить в другом `mysql_query`, а там уже не запрос, а результат работы запроса. возникает ошибка, `mysql_query` возвращает false и сообщение не выводится

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
           records(title, text, date) 
        VALUES ('$_POST[post_title]', '$_POST[post_text]', NOW())";

if(mysql_query($sql, $db)) {
    echo "Success";
}else{
    echo mysql_error($db);
}
```

И еще, никогда не делайте так

> .... VALUES ('$_POST[post_title]', '$_POST[post_text]'...

Это дыра в системе, обязательно защищайтесь от SQL инъекций. В $_POST вам могут передать что угодно, и в лучшем случае запрос просто не выполнится, в худшем, утром сайт не увидите

Comment: не выводится ничего все еще

Comment: А данные точно добавились в базу?

Comment: да, добавляются. Я новичок просто, а как писать тогда?

Comment: Чуть дополнил пример. сейчас что-то выведется? Может у Вас там где-то редирект еще стоит? и Вы просто не видите что что-то выводится?

По поводу "как писать", то посмотрите функцию `mysql_real_escape_string`, также знайте, что расширение mysql в новых версиях PHP является depricated, смотрите в сторону mysqli, а также почитайте о http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php, но это отдельная тема безопасности.

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно конечно еще так

```
    <?php

 if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO records(title, text, date) VALUES ('$_POST[post_title]','$_POST[post_text]', NOW())", $db)) {
    echo "Success";
 }
 ?>
```